# Cooking boneless skinless chicken thighs

Tags: chicken

What's a good approach to cooking boneless skinless chicken thighs relatively quickly if tenderness is a priority?

I know some people like a somewhat chewy texture with chicken thigh but the person I'm cooking for is quite sensitive to it

Comment: How long would you accept as being 'relatively quickly'?

Comment: @Spagirl I guess sub 20 minutes method appropriate for a weeknight dinner.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and tender do not typically go hand in hand.

I get this is not really a direct answer but I slow cook 4 or more at a time and refrigerate.  Then microwave for like 30 seconds as needed.  I use skin with bones (cheaper) and then remove the skin and bones after cooked.  Cooking in the fat works better in a slow cooker and tenderizes.  Yes the chicken does absorb some fat.  But you also melt off all the surface fat.

For direct cooking I would saute with red wine.

I don't have one but a programmable pressure cooker may be your best option.

Comment: Thigh is a main working muscle with lots of connective tissue.  No different that other proteins from main working muscles with connective tissue the way to tenderize is normally this answer, time and patience to break it down, not quick fixes.